# What does #pragma vertex vert_img do in a Unity shader?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, cg

While I built an idea of what vert_img does by observing results, I would like to read a more theoretical explanation that I couldn't find online.

For context, I found this *vert_img* in some shaders that use floating point textures to compute the dynamics of a particle system.

Edit: the confusing thing is that it's declared even if no vertex shaders are defined.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I just found out, **vert_img** is a minimal vertex shader that is defined in **UnityCG.cginc**

```
v2f_img vert_img( appdata_img v )
{
    v2f_img o;
    o.pos = mul (UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
    o.uv = v.texcoord;
    return o;
}
```

Its purpose is to forward the vertex data to the fragment shader. Handy!

Answer (score 2):

#pragma vertex **VERTEX_SHADER_NAME** (vertex method)

#pragma vertex ____ represents the name of vertex shader in Shader code.

Either it is vert_img or any thing else.

[image: shader example]